# passing Parameter values to filter a table in a different sheet using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a data-table value that has for example this value:

`Table name = Employees`

`Column Names = Names, Titles`

The values of the the columns will consist of

`"SamT, Manager"`

`"Nock, Manager"`

`"John, Entry Level"`

`"Kris, HR"`

So If I have this table generated from a sql server table on Sheet Two on my excel spreed sheet, How can I create a Parameter that will help me filer this table automatically by entering values in a different sheet(One). The Parameter can be drop down list of the Titles or just a text box that takes the values. For example I pick "Manager" in the parameter drop down list in the Sheet one and on the next spreed sheet where I have the "Employees" table list only shows the employees with the Manager Title. How can accomplish this using VBA in Excel?

thanks,

Comment: You don't necessarily need VBA. Take a look at MS Query. Here's an old, i.e., Excel 2003-centric, but great post on the topic from Daily Dose of Excel: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/13/parameters-in-excel-external-data-queries/

Comment: Thanks Doug. That was helpful but I was more looking for a way to write a VBA code that will have a linked Parameter. The reason is that it would be easier to make changes to a code in VBA than to go and manually add these parameters via the Excel tools when there are more requests for additional parameters.

Comment: There are different ways to do this. A good one would be to program the ListObject's (Table's) QueryTable object. You could also do something on the SQL Server end of things and Use `CreateParameter` and `AppendParameter`. These are all big learning experiences, though, and you need to do some research into them. I'd still use the MS Query method, and just write some VBA to change the values in teh paramter cells.

Comment: Dough, In that case how do I pass the Parameters in the Query's?

Comment: Take a look at the MS Query documentation on the web. You can figure it out. I'm not going to be able to walk you through it though. Come back here and ask if you get stuck with something specific you'll get help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, you can expand the if statement for more arguments.

On the Sheet1 object you can add:

```
private sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)

if target = Range("YourCell") then
    Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("YOURTABLENAME").Range.AutoFilter Field:=NUMBEROFCORRESPONDING FIELD, Criteria1:="=" & Range("YourCell").value
end if

end sub
```

I haven't tested this so there hopefully there are no typos.